# app crashes on isHidden property

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, autolayout, unrecognized-selector

I just converted the code from objective-c to swift and now there are some unknown crashes occurring in my app.

1. The app crashes on every outlet property whose visibility I change using `selectedView.isHidden = false`. The error is `[Controller _mutableLayoutArrangements]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`
2. When I commented out `isHidden` then `viewDidLoa`d method a crash occur by saying `[Controller _hostsLayoutEngine]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`

I did some research but didn't find an exact reason for this behaviour. But I have some idea that these crashes are due to autolayout constraint crashes. But I'm not sure of this.

I found a line related to crash but I'm not able to solve the issue 
[layoutSublayersOfLayer](http://www.jft0m.com/2017/11/25/%E6%80%A7%E8%83%BD%E7%9B%91%E6%8E%A7/UIView-CALayerDelegate-layoutSublayersOfLayer/):

Comment: what is   "Controllet"  here [Controllet _mutableLayoutArrangements]

Comment: Controller is the viewController in which crash is coming

Comment: is "Controllet" a typo? should be  "Controller"

Comment: thanks I update the question

Comment: Use an exception breakpoint to see on what line your app crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this problem i find is not usual, I checked that these issues I was facing "mutableLayoutArrangements and hostsLayoutEngine" are part of AGSLayer.

Then i checked and found i was importing the AGSLayer delegate. Removing the delegate solved my issue.
Actually previously I was using this for arcGis library.

Answer (score 1):

check your storyboard views they have outlets which are not there in your UIViewController. You need to delete such outlets and retry running the project.

Comment: I checked every outlet is connected in viewController

Comment: some might have extra outlets please check

Comment: I checked each and every out let and IBAction. All the outlet on storyboard is connected in the viewController

Comment: @ParvBhasker What if you delete all those outlets and create them again?